# Angular $http fails to return coherent cache

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous

I have a problem where a page has two components but only one of them is fully rendered.

The problem seem to be related to $http. I have a angular project where I need to construct a page based on RESTful API. The pages are such that I can expect multiple requests for the same data. At the moment, the set of requests are not behaving correctly.

For the sake of the argument (and also because it is a use case), the following page makes the same request twice.

`game.html`:

```
<html ng-app="prvdApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/">
<title>Providence</title>
<script src="/js/angular-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/data-access/data-access.service.js"></script>
<script src="/score-info/score-info.component.js"></script>
<script src="/js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="gameController">
        <score-info game-id="8000"></score-info>
        <score-info game-id="8000"></score-info>
    </div>
</body>
```

`game.js`:

```
angular.module('prvdApp', [
    'scoreInfo',
    'drivesInfo' ]);
angular.
module('prvdApp').
controller('gameController', function() {
});
```

`score-info.component.js`:

```
angular.module('scoreInfo', [
    'dataAccess'
]);
angular.
module('scoreInfo').
component('scoreInfo', {
    templateUrl : '/score-info/score-info.template.html',
    controller : function ScoreInfoController(dataAccess) {
        self = this;
        self.$onInit = function() {
            dataAccess.game(self.gameId).then(function(game) {
                self.game = game;
            });
        }
    },
    bindings : {
        gameId : '<'
    }
});
```

`score-info.template.html`:

```
<div>
Data available: {{ $ctrl.game != undefined }}
</div>
```

`data-access.component.js`:

```
angular.module('dataAccess', []);
angular.
module('dataAccess').
service('dataAccess',
    function DataAccessService($http, $q) {
        self = this;
        self.game = function(game_id) {
            var url = '/api/game/' + game_id;
            return $http.get(url, { cache: true}).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    });
```

The behaviour is as follows:

1. The page renders with the content:

> Data available: false
>
> Data available: false

2. After some hundreds of milliseconds the `$http` -request finishes, the page is updated to the following state where only the latter component is updated.

> Data available: false
>
> Data available: true

It should be noted that the behaviour is the same even if the two components are of different types with different controllers, etc.

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in here? I can't really spot what you're asking!

Comment: The page contains two components but only one of them is updated. Thank you. I will clarify the question.